# How to show specific information in Grafana alerts

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I've configured Grafana to send e-mails based on disk space, and it all works fine.

However, when the e-mails come in, they appear like this[image]

Is there a way to change the **Value:** portion to only show the instanceID and privateIP address and percentage disk space currently used, as opposed to spitting out so much data?

I'm trying to keep things as clean as possible.

I've been reading up on Templates, but it's a little tricky at the moment, and I haven't quite figured it out.

Thanks.